# Getting Leaflet routing control result outside map in a div or table

Tags: leaflet, routing, html, open-source-routing-machine

All of the examples of [Leaflet routing control](https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/) display the result (iterenary) inside the map area.
[image]

I want to display it outside in a `div` or `table` element. There is [ItineraryBuilder](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#l-routing-itinerarybuilder) in the API but no example on how to use it.

My code

```
routing = L.Routing.control({
        waypoints: [
            L.latLng(37.56569, 22.8),
            L.latLng(37.56569, 22.7)
        ],
        routeWhileDragging: true,
        itineraryFormatter: "test"
    }).addTo(map);
```

I want the iterenary to be displayed in textarea below Path Data

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="path-results">Path data</label>
    <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm test" readonly id="path-results" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Coding questions on GIS SE site require relevant existing code to be included in the question, otherwise you are risking it to be closed as not compliant with the site policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward 'official' method to achieve this, but it can be done with a little bit of hacking.

`L.Routing.control` is extension of standard Leaflet `L.control`, which has `.getContainer()` method to retrieve HTML element containing control. With the help of DOM standard methods `.removeChild()` and `.appendChild()`, this control element can be then moved inside desired HTML element.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var routing = L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    L.latLng(37.56569, 22.8),
    L.latLng(37.56569, 22.7)
  ],
  routeWhileDragging: true,
  itineraryFormatter: "test"
}).addTo(map);

var routingControlContainer = routing.getContainer();
var controlContainerParent = routingControlContainer.parentNode;
controlContainerParent.removeChild(routingControlContainer);
var itineraryDiv = document.getElementById('path-results');
itineraryDiv.appendChild(routingControlContainer);
```

Comment: It worked but the size of my div did not match with the routing container

Comment: Since you didn't gave info about `form-control`,  `form-control-sm` and `test` CSS classes, I couldn't check output on your actual situation. Since this is pure HTML CSS problem, I deem that on the basis of the info given in the question, you question was answered.

Comment: i removed 'leaflet-routing-container' class and it worked. routingControlContainer.removeAttribute('class', 'leaflet-routing-container');